How do I get my VSC folder into my Wix website?
I created a program on Visual studio code for text to speech and am trying to implement it into my Wix website. In order to add a custom code section on Wix, you need a server url. However, I am struggling to find the server url. In my VSC folder, I have three different files (index.html, styles.css, and script.js) and all are necessary for the program to run correctly.
I attempted putting the terminal output when I ran the program in VSC, but it is not a url and was deemed invalid. I attempted putting all three code snippets into one large code snippet in the Custom Code section (under advanced settings on Wix) but it did not appear at all. I copy and pasted all three code snippets into the Wix HTML code embedding, but only the HTML part showed up and worked.
Is there a way to do this all in one? Or is there a way for me to code text to speech entirely in HTML?

VSC project(with index.html, styles.css, script.js) into your Wix website, you will need to host your files somewhere online and then link to them from your Wix site.
By hosting your files on a platform like GitHub Pages, you get a URL that you can use in your Wix site. You can either embed this URL in an iframe or link to your CSS and JavaScript files directly in the custom HTML embed. In this way, you can keep your index.html, styles.css, and script.js working together seamlessly on your Wix website.

Thank you so much, you just saved my project!!

That's my pleasure.
